# giving error msg at wrong condition

Tags: php, conditional-statements, msg

```
<?php
$dir = 'dir';
$exclude = array('.','..','.htaccess');
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtolower($_GET['q']) : '';
$res = opendir($dir);
if (strlen($q) < 3) {
echo "Search must be longer than 3 characters.<br><br>";
} else {
if (!( ($q == "mp3") || ($q == "wav") || ($q == ""))){


while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) {
if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {

$nicefile = str_replace(".mp3", "", "$file");
$info = pathinfo($file);
if (($info["extension"] == "mp3") || ($info["extension"] == "wav")) {

echo "<a href='http://domainname/filename.php?name=$file'>$nicefile</a>";
echo "<br>";


}elseif(!isset($errorMsg)){
$errorMsg = "ERROR: File not found.<br><br>";
}else{}
}elseif(!isset($errorMsge)){
$errorMsge = "ERROR: File not found.<br><br>";
}else{}
}
if (isset($errorMsge)){echo $errorMsge;}
else{}
if (isset($errorMsg)){echo $errorMsg;}
else{}
}else{echo"ERROR: File not found.<br><br>";}
}
closedir($res);
?>
```

this is like a search script and the problem is @

> if(strpos(strtolower($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude))
>   {

it shows the error msg whether there is results or file named like search query or not.

any idea how to fix that?